# Bootstrap 3 vertically stacked social buttons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create this button in CSS/HTML:

[image]

Here is what I have:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can create this perfectly?

Here is my code

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
  .btn {
    padding: 14px 24px;
    border: 0 none;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  .btn:focus,
  .btn:active:focus {
    outline: 0 none;
  }
  .btn-primary {
    background: #d5e14d;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  .btn-primary:hover {
    background: #d5e14d;
  }
</style>
<button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i> Instagram</button>
```

Comment: Try http://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-social/

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. It's a good practice to create your own css class for specific buttons. Here i create the class .btn-green than i made all changes to look like your example. See below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<style>
  .btn {
    padding:0;
    height: 50px;
 line-height: 50px;
    border: 0 none;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  .btn:focus,
  .btn:active:focus {
    outline: 0 none;
  }
  .btn-green {
    background: #d5e14d;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  .btn-green:hover {
    background: #d5e14d;
  }
  
  .btn-green i {
    margin: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #C6D157;
    padding:0 15px;
    font-size: 25px;
 height: 100%;
    line-height: 50px;
 float:left;
 display: inline-block;
   }
   
   .btn-green span{
 margin:0;
 height: 100%;
    line-height: 50px;
 padding:0 10px;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 13px;
   }
  
</style>
<button class="btn btn-green">
  <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
  <span>Instagram</span>
</button>
```